# How to add css components / blocks from custom css framework?

Tags: divshot

Is it possible to use css components from custom CSS file? I am using a CSS framework of my own  which is **not based on bootstrap**. I uploaded my .css but I don't see the components listed in the list of components. Also i see only two libraries available i.e bootstrap and generic.

What I want is, if I upload my own .css file... components / css-blocks from my .css file to be available in the components list. Are there some options / settings for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment I'm afraid but we're planning to introduce more CSS frameworks and the ability to add your own frameworks in the future. We want Divshot to be completely extensible. If you'd like to be notified when this feature is available (and possibly beta test), please get in touch with us at support@divshot.com.